# Automated UI tests for web and desktop applications

Tags: angularjs, testing, automation, automated-tests, ui-automation

I have a web application developed using HTML5 & AngularJS. I want to develop automated UI tests for this application.

Questions

1. It seems like Protractor is the standard tool which people generally use for automated UI testing for Angular application. Is there any other testing framework (like coded UI test) which I should try or compare against Protractor?
2. In the web application I have map component developed using Open Layer3 & Open street map as base layer. I plot some objects on map, something like this one. Is there any way I can detect the plotted objects on map using any tool?
3. My workflow is such that first I make some operation from web UI then use some other desktop application to complete the workflow. So my manual test case first have steps for web UI then use the desktop application to complete the workflow. I want to automate such test cases.
   Can I do automation both for web & desktop application using Protractor? If not then what would be the options to automate such cases where I have to do operation on both desktop and web application?

Regards,
Atul

Comment: You can do this with Protactor, see https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive/pull/700/files for example. 

But you can also try Serenity BDD, see https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-core which also works with AngularJS and has a fluent API and supports with PageObject-pattern.